# While loop until a file exists in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to write `wait` until a file exists in bash. How do I do this?

I tried this but it doesnt work:

```
while [ ! -f outputs\/$trace\_hist_len_$hist_len\_page_size_$page_size\.out]; do
echo "waiting for outputs\/$trace\_hist_len_$hist_len\_page_size_$page_size\.out";
done
```

It seems to have a syntax error.

Comment: Okay, your formatting probably doesn't look right anymore after indenting the code, sorry about that. Can you check whether your variables look right? And in the future, please indent code with 4 spaces or `Ctrl-K` so you don't have to escape anything!

Comment: Yeah, It's correct. Thanks for the formatting.

Comment: Please post the rest of your code as well. What are the values of `$trace`, `$hist_len` and `$page_size`? What is the error you're getting? Why do you need to escape the `/`?

Comment: `wait` is probably not the command you are looking for.  `wait` will pause a script until all child processes are done, at which point it will continue.

Comment: I think you have your / and \ mixed up.  Path names in bash (even in cygwin) use the / character as the delimiter.

Comment: You formatting is still terribly bad. You'll keep get -1 from me until learn to clean up your examples out of irrelevant (aka garbage).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
while : ; do
    [[ -f "/path/to/file" ]] && break
    echo "Pausing until file exists."
    sleep 1
done
```

Without using something like `inotify`, this is about the limit of what you're going to be able to do.

The `while` loop above just uses `:` as its conditional which pretty much just means "do it until we kill it."

The important line is the `[[` test.  The test conditional here does not use the `if` statement.  This is because `[[` is an actual command and *NOT* part of the `if` statement.  This executes `[[ -f "/path/to/file" ]]` and the `&&` checks the exit status of the `[[` command and executes the following statement if that exit status is `0` (success).  The following statement here is `break` which will close out the current loop that your script is in.

Note: In `bash` it is highly recommended that you use `[[` instead of `[`.  It has all of the capabilities of `[` but is far more powerful and simple to use.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with while [ ! -f "path" ]; echo Whatever;done In fact, I think your example is silly because you can do: while [[ ! -f path ]]; do echo silly;done Further, the question was about a syntax error, and not about avoiding it with "highly recommended" and _less portable_ bash constructs.

Comment: No, the question was how can he accomplish a specific task and that his one attempt had failed.  He asked how he can accomplish the task, I answered the question.  If it is not the best method to obtain the results, then the votes will reflect that.  You are correct, using the syntax you indicated is perfectly valid.  However when using `[[` and simply quoting his filename, it will likely be interpreted more appropriately by the `[[` which is one of the reasons it is recommended over `[`.

Comment: Quote: I want to write wait until a file exists in bash. How do I do this?

Comment: You mean _your_ vote will reflect that. His loop is valid with the exception of one missing space character.

Comment: You can't vote on your own answers.  Nice try.

Comment: Whatever, I'll _give_ you a vote. Silly argument, idk why I got so worked up over this. Let's move on dude.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин quote: "idk why I got so worked up over this". I guess it's just POSIX love :)

Answer (score 5):

The space between the file argument and the closing bracket is important.

```
if [ -f "path" ]; then echo good;fi

if [-f "path"] ; then  echo bad;fi
if [ -f "path"]; then  echo bad;fi
if [-f "path" ]; then  echo bad;fi
```